# Show the stock status option from product settings "Inventory" to "General" tab in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In woocommerce by default, the `stock status` option is under the **"inventory"** tab.

How I can show the exact option under the `general` tab?

Searching, I stumble across this code inside `woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php`:

```
public function set_stock_status( $status = 'instock' ) {
    $valid_statuses = wc_get_product_stock_status_options();

    if ( isset( $valid_statuses[ $status ] ) ) {
        $this->set_prop( 'stock_status', $status );
    } else {
        $this->set_prop( 'stock_status', 'instock' );
    }
}
```

Then inside `functions.php`, I have added:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'check_stock_status' );`
```

But nothing happen. May be I'm calling the wrong function.

P/S : I'm using WC 2.6.4

Comment: @LoicTheAztec im not trying to move it, just to duplicate the option. If it is hardcoded, which file?

Answer (score 1):

To display a duplicated Stock status setting select field in Woocommerce **"Product data" *metabox*** under **"General" *tab***, you can use one of the following available action hooks:

- **`woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data`**
- `woocommerce_product_options_pricing` *(hidden on some product types)*
- `woocommerce_product_options_downloads` *(hidden if product is not downloadable)*
- `woocommerce_product_options_tax` *(hidden on some product types)*

**The code** *(commented the "wrapper_class" argument to force the display)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'stock_status_in_general_options_settings' );
function stock_status_in_general_options_settings() {
    global $post, $product_object;

    woocommerce_wp_select(
        array(
            'id'            => '_stock_status',
            'value'         => $product_object->get_stock_status( 'edit' ),
            // 'wrapper_class' => 'stock_status_field hide_if_variable hide_if_external hide_if_grouped',
            'label'         => __( 'Stock status', 'woocommerce' ),
            'options'       => wc_get_product_stock_status_options(),
            'desc_tip'      => true,
            'description'   => __( 'Controls whether or not the product is listed as "in stock" or "out of stock" on the frontend.', 'woocommerce' ),
        )
    );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme).

[image]

Comment: I got this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function get_stock_status() on null in..." . I think it's because I'm using WC 2.6.4 .Sorry forgot to highlight that.

Comment: Anyway I changed global $product_object to $product and set the value to $product->stock_status( 'edit' ), and this time the error is "Fatal error: Call to a member function stock_status() on array in..." . Clearly I'm still using some new WC 3.x syntax here but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @NazrinNoorzan My answer code is made to work only with Woocommerce 3+… You didn't explicitly restricted your question to Woocommerce 2.6.x and mostly nobody uses outdated Woocommerce version 2.6.x. I will try to add later a version code for Woocommerce 2.6.x …

Comment: yeah my bad. The reason why I stick with the old version is because if I update it, there are a lot of things broken. Anyway, have you got the answer for WC 2.6.x version?